# Add a Gradient Bar over the navbar-fixed-top. On scrolling the Gradient bar should be hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my Navigation bar to be navbar-fixed-top. The gradient bar should be on top of the Navbar just like in the attached image. I have tried this code but the navbar-fixed-top class hides the gradient bar under it and the gradient bar is no more visible. I want a pure Css solution to it without any jQuery or javascript.

[image]

```css
body{ background: grey!important;
}
/*+++++++ COLOR BAR ++++++++*/
.color-bar{ width: 100%;
         height: 4px; 
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0c24b 0%, #b5d56a 20%, #ea7066 40%, #84bed6 60%, #a597e7 80%, #ea77ad 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f0c24b 0%, #b5d56a 20%, #ea7066 40%, #84bed6 60%, #a597e7 80%, #ea77ad 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #f0c24b 0%, #b5d56a 20%, #ea7066 40%, #84bed6 60%, #a597e7 80%, #ea77ad 100%);
 } 

/*+++++++++ NAVBAR white */
.navbar {background-color: white;  
}

/* iNCREASING NAVBAR SIZE */
.navbar-static-top, .navbar-header, .navbar-collapse { min-height: 105px !important ; }


/*++++++++++ NAVBAR BOTTOM DECORATION */
.nav-decor{ 
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 10px;
 left: 0px;
 bottom: -10px;
        background-image: url(../Images/shape.png); 
        background-repeat: repeat-x;}

.container-fluid{ padding-left: 5% !important;
           padding-right: 5% !important; 
 }

 .navbar-nav{ position: absolute;
        right: 15%;
              top:30%;
       font-size: 20px;
 }

.navbar-nav>li>a>span {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;   
}
.navbar-nav>li>a{ font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
               font-weight: 400;
 }

/*++++++++ NAVBAR LINKS COLOR +++++++*/
.color-1>a { color: #f26f29;}
.color-2>a { color: rgb(255, 186, 6); }
.color-3>a { color: #a9d63b; }
.color-4>a { color: #6ab3d1; }
.color-5>a { color: #907ee2; }
.color-6>a { color: #e868a7; }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid color-bar"></div>
 
<nav class="navbar navbav-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">    
  <div class="navbar-header">     
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Images/logo-xs.png" alt="Intelligram"></a>
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
  </div>
    
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
    <li class="color-1 active">
     <a href="index.html">
      <span>Home</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="color-2">
     <a href="index.html">
     <span>Classes</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li class="color-3">
      <a href="index.html">
       <span>Pages</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li class="color-4">
      <a href="index.html">
       <span>Blogs</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li class="color-5">
      <a href="index.html">
       <span>Store</span>
      </a>
     </li>
     <li class="color-6">
      <a href="index.html">
       <span>Events</span>
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>   
<div class="nav-decor"></div>
</nav>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDQ6o.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDQ6o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [**z-index** feature](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of CSS. By using z-index, you can prioritize different layers in your source by pulling some forward or pushing some back.

If you add the CSS line `z-index: 10;` to your .color-bar class, it should pull it in front of anything with a z-index lower than 10 (default is 0).

Comment: It worked. Is it necessary to give z-index to both the classes i.e. color-bar and navbar-fixed-top because when i dont give navbar-fixed-top any index it doesn't work?